# Hiding text on small viewports using span class and media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have tried to use media queries and `display: none` in my css to hide part of my nav bar text when the screen size is less than 600px.

Why does it not work - the original link text remains at any screen width:

```css
@media all and (min-width: 0.1px) and (max-width: 599.9px) {
  #mobhide {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="/about.html">ABOUT<span class="mobhide"> US</span></a>
<span style="width:1vw;display:inline-block">|</span>
<a href="/cookies.html">COOKIES<span class="mobhide"> & PRIVACY</span></a>
<span style="width:1vw;display:inline-block">|</span>
<a href="/terms.html">TERMS<span class="mobhide"> & CONDITIONS</span></a>
```

Comment: You are using a ID selector, but in the HTML you are using a class selector? Change the selector to `.mobhide`

Comment: You might also put this in the CSS:`style="width:1vw;display:inline-block"` and get it out of the markup

Comment: that is a different span element and only appears twice on my page :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using class`.mobhide` in HTML and using `#mobhide` in CSS, plus avoid using `!important` and `max-width:600px` alone will do what you want.

```css
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobhide {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="/about.html">ABOUT<span class="mobhide"> US</span></a>
<span style="width:1vw;display:inline-block">|</span>
<a href="/cookies.html">COOKIES<span class="mobhide"> & PRIVACY</span></a>
<span style="width:1vw;display:inline-block">|</span>
<a href="/terms.html">TERMS<span class="mobhide"> & CONDITIONS</span></a>
```

Take a look at this blog post about [The Difference Between ID and Class](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: Of course! Only just getting to grips with CSS properly, thanks. Also made me realise that I have used id incorrectly elsewhere when I should be using class.